# Where do good questions go?

Tags: discussion

It seems now few questions show enough serious sense, and lots are just random requirements.

Where do good ones go, are they dilutioned, deleted or just posted less?

Comment: Maybe they've already been asked?

Comment: Opinion-based, I guess

Comment: @LuisMendo Agree, but I'll either have it deleted automatically or if it reach +5

Comment: +1, this question is one of the appropriate ones.

Comment: I think a question like this is not necessarily opinion based, and could be answered with statistics. But, as is, it's not clear what what kinds of questions you're talking about.

Comment: "Random requirements" seems to be the method I use when creating challenges though.  e. g. Space Cleaners!.

Answer (score 1):

> Where do good ones go, are they dilutioned, deleted or just posted less?

They aren't posted yet, they're still in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges); the majority of good new questions are there. Good questions depend on your opinion; a bad question in your opinion can be a good question in another's perspective.

Nobody could delete their question once answered, so they can't be deleted. People won't want to delete their questions if they're well recieved anyway. So saying that they're "dilutioned" totally depends on your opinion.